# Checking the channel name

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', (oldMessage, newMessage, role, args, guild) => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.content === '.') {
    if (message.guild.channel === 'dot-wars') {
      message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
        var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Dot Master!');
        member.removeRole(role);
      })
  }
    var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Dot Master!');
    message.member.addRole(role);
 }
});
```

okay so what i want to do is when someone sends a '.' the bot will remove the 'Dot Master!' role from everyone in the server and then add the 'Dot Master!' role to the person that sent it, but only if it is in the 'dot-wars' channel.

Answer (score 2):

A text channel has a [`name`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=name) property for reading its name. However, make sure you're checking the channel the message was sent in, not the guild ([`Message#channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel)).

```js
if (message.channel.name === 'dot-wars') {
  ...
}
```